# Save data to MS Access db.accdb

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

I wrote an application in C# with WPF. When I debug locally, everything works well!

But when I pack it using InstallShield or (other system packing) and put it on another computer, the application does not work. The data is not being saved into the database.

There are no errors, and the problem is just on release.

I put on the test machine(W10): Runtime access -ADO.NET -ACE.PROVIDER...
so where am I going wrong?

Please help me!

My connection string:

```
InitializeComponent(); 
con.ConnectionString = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BDIAI.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: Silly question: does that `BDIAI.accdb` file **exists** on the other computer where your app doesn't work? Or does your code create it, when it's not there yet?

Answer (score 0):

of corse exists!
You can download the project to verify..if you want...

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AiPWNiaxpd8yglVEct9EV-aZ7u_N